# Asus Laptop only booting into BIOS (help!)

Tags: windows-8, bios, laptop-repair

Recently I closed my laptop, set it on a table then the next time I went to pick it up it went from boot up straight to the BIOS. I immediately pressed ESC and tried to exit. The computer would go black for a split second and then come back to the BIOS. I tried resetting default BIOS settings and the computer reset then went straight to bios again.

Here is the info about my laptop

```
Brand:             ASUS
Model:             UX302L
RAM:               8GB (installed myself)
Processor:         i5-4200
Operating System:  Windows 8
```

My question is how do I get past the bios into windows or at least windows start up repair?

Comment: Please ask the question, or it may be closed.

Comment: Sorry about that, question added

Comment: If you're getting into startup repair (as mentioned in your question) you're actually getting beyond the BIOS already.  It sounds like your OS is corrupted somehow.

Comment: My questions asks how I can get past BIOS into startup repair. I can only get into BIOS right now

Comment: Before your computer dumps you into the BIOS, it should be telling you some sort of error message. Also, since you *can* get into the BIOS, look around for something that will reset it to defaults, which should be a safe thing to do. Without an error message, it's like asking "My car won't start, why?" There isn't much information to go on (even if you do know the make/model).

Comment: Yea I understand how little information you have to go on and I wish I got an error message that I could look up. Upon closer look apparently my HDD isn't showing up on the boot order. Weird seeing how this is a one month old laptop. I am going to open it up and check the connection soon

Comment: Asus BIOS-es and UEFIs have boot selection menu on the last tab, you can choose an item you want to boot to - Windows should be there somewhere. Unless your EFI partition is corrupted and UEFI doesn't know how to boot Windows. Could you post a photo of the last tab?

Answer (score 2):

Try these instructions:

> 1. In Boot Menu -> Change FastStart to [Disable]
> 2. In Security Menu -> Change Secure Boot to [Disable]
> 3. Then 'Save Configuration & Exit', when the BIOS screen appears again
> 4. Go to the Boot Menu again -> Change Launch CSM to [Enable]

This worked for me with Windows 10 on an Asus ZenBook UX330UA

From [My Microsoft Operations Manager Experience blog](http://mymomexperience.blogspot.com/2013/09/asus-ux31a-unable-to-pass-bios-screen.html)